# Create initially deferred trigger syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please help get my head around [trigger creation syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
create trigger cool_trigger
    after insert or update
    on custom_object_reference
    deferrable initially deferred
    for each statement
    execute procedure do_something();

syntax error at or near "deferrable"
```

I am using `PostgreSQL 9.6.7`

Comment: Never used that defer thing but from the documentation, it sounds like you should either put `DEFERRABLE` or `INITIALLY DEFERRED`, not both - have you tried putting only one?

Comment: Tried different ways, neither worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only a constraint trigger can be deferred, so you'll have to use

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER ...
```

As the documentation says, you can only do this for `AFTER ROW` triggers.

Comment: Okay :( Then I have to look for some way to still do this (run code on commit if that table was changed).